# Openmpi installation

Tags: linux-mint, mpi

I have just started to use Linux Mint for academic reasons and ran into an error as I was trying to install openmpi-2.0.1.
I am getting following error as I am trying to make check

```
    make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers'
Making check in etc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/etc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/etc'
Making check in mpi/c
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/mpi/c'
Making check in profile
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/mpi/c/profile'
  CC       pstatus_c2f.lo
rm: cannot remove '.libs/pstatus_c2f.o': Permission denied
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create .libs/pstatus_c2f.o: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [pstatus_c2f.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/mpi/c/profile'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/mpi/c'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Earlier I got an error

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/thanhnt/openmpi-1.6/ompi/debuggers'
CCLD predefined_gap_test
libtool: link: cannot find the library `../../ompi/libmpi.la' or unhandled argument `../../ompi/libmpi.la'
make[3]: *** [predefined_gap_test] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/thanhnt/openmpi-1.6/ompi/debuggers'
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/thanhnt/openmpi-1.6/ompi/debuggers'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thanhnt/openmpi-1.6/ompi'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error
```

Even after fixing the permission error above, I still got:

> libtool: error: cannot find the library '../../ompi/libmpi.la' or unhandled argument '../../ompi/libmpi.la'
>
> make[3]: *** [predefined_gap_test] Error 1
>
> make[3]: Leaving directory /home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers' make[2]: *** [check-am]
>
> Error 2 make[2]: Leaving directory /home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers' make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1

Comment: You've some issues with permissions (`Permission denied`). You're probably mixing `sudo` with normal user credentials. Please include the info how do you installing it. You probably need to `make clean`, fix the permissions and try again.

Comment: Even after getting permissions and doinfg a make clean...

Comment: `libtool:   error: cannot find the library '../../ompi/libmpi.la' or unhandled argument '../../ompi/libmpi.la'
make[3]: *** [predefined_gap_test] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers'
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/kuljeet/Downloads/openmpi-2.0.1/ompi/debuggers'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
`

Comment: The above error is what I am getting @kenorb

Comment: Can you include the command how are you installing it? Just `make` in the source folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it with `icc` [intel compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-linux-installation-help). Make sure you're using the recent version, so it's compatible with your gcc. Then you need to configure and compile it by following these instructions suggested by [@liqizuiyang](http://muchong.com/html/201408/7827406.html):

1. Copy the source code to `$HOME` and decompress.

   ```
   tar -xf openmpi-2.0.1.bz2
   ```
2. Create a new directory named `build` under your `$HOME`.

   ```
   mkdir build
   ```

   > The 'build' directory is a sub-directory of $HOME, not 'openmpi-1.6.4'. Both 'build' and 'openmpi-1.6.4' are sub-directories of $HOME.
3. Go to build and set environmental variables.

   ```
   cd build
   export CC=icc
   export CXX=icpc
   export FC=ifort
   export F77=ifort
   export CFLAGS=-O2
   export CXXFLAGS=-O2
   export FCFLAGS=-O2
   export FFLAGS=-O2
   ```
4. Run configure.

   ```
   ../openmpi-2.0.1/configure --prefix="$HOME/code/openmpi-2.0.1
   ```
5. Build openmpi.

   ```
   make
   ```
6. Run the test suite.

   ```
   make check
   ```
7. Install.

   ```
   make install
   ```

---

Here are some other guides for building Open MPI:

- [How do I build Open MPI?](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building#easy-build)
- [Requirements to Build from a Developer Checkout](https://www.open-mpi.org/source/building.php)
- see [HACKING](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/master/HACKING) file in the source folder

---

Another workaround, as suggested in the [FAQ](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=troubleshooting), is to build Open MPI as a static library by configuring Open MPI with `--disable-shared` and `--enable-static`. This has the same effect as `--disable-dlopen`, but it also makes `libmpi.a` (as opposed to a shared library).

---

If you still got the problem following the official guides, please [raise the issue at open-mpi](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues), there could be some issue specific to your Linux distribution.