# install Open MPI on CentOS 6.8 "requires a C99 compiler error"

Tags: software-installation, mpi

I am trying to install Open MPI [2.1.0 version](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v2.1/downloads/openmpi-2.1.0.tar.gz) on our CentOS machine. 
I followed these steps:

```
tar -xvf openmpi-*
cd openmpi-*
./configure --prefix="/home/$USER/.openmpi"

*** C compiler and preprocessor
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) unsupported
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... unsupported
configure: WARNING: Open MPI requires a C99 compiler
configure: error: Aborting.
```

I searched for same problems like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331630/106248) and tried to install C99 and whatever missing. 
and no progress. Do you have comment or solution?

Comment: What version of `gcc` is installed?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)

Comment: Well, that's definitely a C99 compiler (and C89).  Could you add the part from `config.log` where it fails to compile the last test? (or put the whole `config.log` on http://pastebin.com or somesuch place and link to it?)

Comment: I provided it in my [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6whn7bn9pv6s0o7/config.log?dl=0)

Comment: It looks like `gcc` is acting like a C++ compiler... I don't know why. You didn't link `gcc` to `g++` or something similar?

Comment: As far I know and checked the `bashrc` I did not.

Comment: CentOS 6.8 comes with gcc 4.4.7.  Does your gcc come from a special repository, such as one of the Software Collections?

Comment: I don't know. It's a shared machine. But I have root access. do you suggest to update or replace the gcc compiler?

Comment: No, don't change the installed compiler; that can break other things. I see from your logs that it's from devtoolset-2; I'll see if I can reproduce your compilation errors with that.